# pandas - ParserError: Unknown string format: Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have date strings that's generated using unix milliseconds.

This is how the date string looks like.

`2020-01-01 00:04:59.999`.

I saved the data into a csv file.

I'm loading the data using `pd.read_csv` and then I'm trying to parse the date like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

`ParserError: Unknown string format: Timestamp`

Can someone tell me how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have a `Timestamp` word instead of one of the dates

For example:

```
Timestamp, 3 
Timestamp, 3
2020-01-01 00:04:59.999, 3
```

Try to open your csv in any editor and search for Timestamp